# I'm trying to create a matrix using a loop to try an work out True Diversity

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to use the ‘d’ function to estimate qD for q=0,1 and 2 and as this function only takes one community and one value of q at a time, trying to write a short loop to work out everything and trying this code -

for(i in 1:nrow(twice.comm)){

- for(j in 1:3){
- ```
  qD[i,j] <- d(twice.comm[i, ], q=j-1)
  ```
- }
- }
  and the error I get is:- Error in d(twice.comm[i, ], q = j - 1) : could not find function "d"
  Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: I would suggest adding tags for whatever language and library you are using to attract people that know stuff about the specifics of your context.

Comment: thank you, I have added the tag - R - I'm not sure what library it's using unfortunately